# Ubuntu 9.04 server install hangs as DomU with HVM

Tags: ubuntu, xen, virtualization

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 9.04 server as DomU using hardware virtualization. Whenever I boot up the domain, the splash screen works well, but as soon as I select "Install Ubuntu server", the domain keeps hanging with 100% CPU utilization indefinitly.

About 50% of the time, the following message is shown, the other 50% of the time, no message is shown at all:

```
ACPI: DMI BIOS year==0, assuming ACPI-capable machine
```

I tried various settings of `acpi=0`, `acpi=1` in the domain's config file, I tried specifying `acpi=off` as kernel argument, I also tried `acpi=force`.

I am now run out of ideas, why the kernel won't boot. Neither "Install Ubuntu server" nor "Check disk for errors" will work, but Memtest86 works fine from the ISO.

Anybody got a hint how to proceed. I have to confess that I am quite new to Xen.

**Edit:** added, that it is for the server version.

I tried upgrading from previous installs as well.  I could install 8.04 LTS and upgrade to 8.10, but after an upgrade to 9.04 the kernel hangs again. I suppose it "simply" is a kernel issue of 9.04.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the alternate install CD/DVD? Sometimes there are problems with ACPI and the GUI install. It happens on the desktop version a lot as well. Most times the problem is resolved with the alternate install CD/DVD

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try it. I see, I forgot to mention I am trying to install the server version. Don't know if this one has an alternate install CD.